# Mui theme not applying if within a wrapper component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, components

With React (typescript) and MUI (5.4.2), I'm trying to put everything regarding styles within a single file, wrapping everything in my `App.tsx`.

**Issue: The custom MUI theme does not apply to the rest of my app (fallback to default MUI theme)**

The whole thing worked fine when the `ThemeProvider` component was placed directly within the `App.tsx` file, but broke as soon as I placed it elsewhere. I need to keep a separated component, for I'll add **Elastic UI** on top of MUI later on.

My `App.tsx` file:

```js
function App() {
   <UiProvider>
      // ...whole app
   </UiProvider>
}
```

The `UiProvider` component is a simple wrapper component as it follows:

```js
import {ThemeProvider} from "@mui/styles";
import {CustomTheme} from "../../themes/CustomTheme";
import {createTheme, Theme} from "@mui/material/styles";

const UiProvider = (props: any) => {

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={CustomTheme}>
            {props.children}
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
}

export default UiProvider
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `@mui/styles` is the legacy styling solution for MUI, if this is for v5, perhaps the import for `ThemeProvider` should be:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
```